# gRPC: Push notification from server using C++

Tags: c++, grpc

Based on this website https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/ , there are 4 modes of gRPC. May I know which is the most suitable mode for us to push notifications from server in gRPC using C++?

Answer (score 1):

4 "modes" is a bit of a misnomer. Think of it more as each of the channels, client->server and server->client, being in one of two modes: unary or streaming.

If the client sends one and exactly one message to the server, then the client->server channel is unary, streaming otherwise. The same logic applies to the server->client channel.

Whichever one you should use for "push notifications" depends on the same thing as for any other RPC: How many messages does each peer get to send as part of a single RPC.